# Infinite loop when playing a sound

Tags: windev

I want a sound to be played in a loop until an on/off button is off.

I use this code:

```
WHILE BTN_Bouton73..Enfoncé=1
    Son(S_chemin+"H3.wav",sonBoucle)
END
```

But it goes into an infinite loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
WHILE BTN_Bouton73..Enfoncé=1
    Son(S_chemin+"H3.wav",sonBoucle)
    Multitask(-1)
END
```

I  think you could realese button to stop

It give control back to Windows : see [documentation](http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?3015004&name=multitask_function)